# MySQL REXEXP doesn't work propertly

Tags: mysql, regex

`SELECT 'pharase' REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z]+'` - it verifies that the phrase does not contain English chars (or not?).

Why is query `SELECT '123g' REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z]+' -> 1` show 1 instead 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a string only contains English chars, use

```
SELECT 'pharase' REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]+$'
```

where:

- `^` - asserts the position at the start of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `$` - the end of string

`SELECT '123g' REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z]+' -> 1` shows `1` because the string contains `123`, non-letters, a partial match is found with `REGEXP` (unlike `LIKE` that requires a full string match).

Comment: You may use `NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z]'` to get an entry that does not contain an English letter. Or `REGEXP '^[^A-Za-z]+$'`

Comment: How can I check that a phrase does not contain English chars without use `NOT REGEXP`(`NOT REGEXP  [a-zA-z]`)?

Comment: (Terminology) `^` and `$` "anchor" the regexp to the start and end.

Comment: As I stated in the answer, *`^` asserts the position at the start of the string* and *`$` the end of string*. OK, *repetitio est mater studiorum*.